# Getting exception while connecting to oracle database using JSP program

Tags: jsp, docker

I have create a jsp program and added in tomcat docker while testing in local desktop i am getting below exception.

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could
>   not establish the connection.

i am using oracle database 12c docker.

First i have create below stack file.

stack file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  oracle:
    image: sath89/oracle-12c:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "1521:1521"
    stop_grace_period: 1m0s
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
    networks:
      - fronter
  jsp:
    image: bitroid/jsp-db-docker
    ports:
      - "8888:8080"
    networks:
      - fronter
    depends_on:
      - oracle
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
networks:
  fronter:
```

after creating above stack file i used below command to deploy docker in local system.

$docker stack deploy jsp_oracle -c pwdcmdstack.yml

and after deploying i have provisioned oracle database docker with below scripts.

```
docker exec -it --user root jsp_oracle_oracle.1.zqz4r7k4x1cxdagh9fj415u5p /bin/bash -c "apt-get update -y;apt-get install git -y --force-yes"

docker exec -it --user root jsp_oracle_oracle.1.zqz4r7k4x1cxdagh9fj415u5p /bin/bash -c "git clone https://github.com/hemanth22/Oracle_database.git"

docker exec -it --user root jsp_oracle_oracle.1.zqz4r7k4x1cxdagh9fj415u5p /bin/bash -c "chmod -R 777 Oracle_database;cd /Oracle_database;ls -la"

docker exec -it --user oracle jsp_oracle_oracle.1.zqz4r7k4x1cxdagh9fj415u5p /bin/bash -c "netstat -nlpt"

docker exec -it --user oracle jsp_oracle_oracle.1.zqz4r7k4x1cxdagh9fj415u5p /bin/bash -c "ls && cd Oracle_database && ls && bash login.sh"
```

Can you please check and advice how get ride of the `java.sql.SQLRecoverableException`

Thanks and regards,
Hemanth.

Answer (score 0):

Cause: 
This error occurs when there are some issues with the Firewall on the Oracle server.
Solution: 
​To resolve this issue, ensure that the Firewall is open from both sides of the network, that is the Oracle Database should be able to connect back to ambari-server. And on the OS, ensure that the iptables or firewall is stopped or allows traffic on port 1521.

Ref: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/150193/io-error-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-t.html

Comment: i have checked the blog but i could see it is an issue for ambari server, but i am using tomcat server and more over i have add to ports 1521,8080,8888 using this command : firewall-cmd --add-port=1521/tcp,8080/tcp,8888/tcp --permanent --zone=public and after adding ports to firewall i have done reload also

Comment: Hi all,

Issue solved for me instead of adding localhost i have added ip address of oracle docker hence resolved.

When i have configured localhost it is point to tomcat docker instead pointing to oracle docker.

Comment: Happy to hear :)